# Changing cell background color based on two cell data value in Datagridview

Tags: datagridview, c#-3.0, desktop-application

I have one data-grid view which is bind dynamically. and it contain data like below screen shot.

[image: Data-Grid View]

Now problem is i want change cell color  based on data value.
i want to deduct `tamount-paymentamont` and if it >=1 then i want to set this two cell color as a `red` and other as `green`.at every new data bind.

I try this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405591/update-datagridview-cell-background-color-based-on-row-data) but not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this at bind time

```
  for (int n = 0; n < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); n++)
            {
                double i = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells["tamount"].Value.ToString().Replace('.', ','));
                double j = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells["paymentamount"].Value.ToString().Replace('.', ','));
                double total = i - j;
                if (total >= 1)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells["tamount"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells["paymentamount"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightPink;

                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells["tamount"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells["paymentamount"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                }

            }
```